# All System.Threading.Timer instances in the process (including new ones) stops working after some while

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I am encountering following issue in my .Net application:

It is a game server so there are around 150 threads to process all time-related logic, and some of them are Threading.Timer instances. The server was running fine at the beginning and to some point all timers stops working. I tried to start new timers via script executor. The new timers could be started but they are not firing events neither.

Anyone has idea about what could cause all the timers stop working in the process? I am not aware how could this happen theoretically.

Comment: Do you keep their references? Maybe GC collects them.

Comment: Yes. In fact the application has been working for several years without this issue. That's why I feel this is weird.

Comment: _"game server...150 threads to process all time-related logic"_ - that's terribly inefficient

Comment: 150 threads is little bit toooo much.... I never had so much threads, my pc will crash if I create so much threads.

Comment: Sounds like you're exhausting the thread pool - if no pool threads are available, you'll end up with the symptoms similar to what you describe.

Answer (score 1):

`System.Threading.Timer`  *"[executes a single callback method on a **thread pool thread** at regular intervals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx)"*.  Considering you are using 150 threads, its possible you are exhausing the thread pool.

Additionally, if you handler takes too long to process an event, Timer might fall behind and queue updates.

### Re-think your design

Unless its a major component like scene loading; or audio playback; game makers generally avoid threading in games for reasons of reliability and simplicity.

Instead you may want to consider using:

- deferred processing - delay processing until some time later
- batch processing - rather than processing 10,000 items, process a batch of 100 items every 10ms

[image]

Gregory, J, ["Game Engine Architecture"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1568814135)

Comment: I understand that. But:
1. if the pool is exhausted, the new one must not be started.
2. if the callback is taking too long, the behavior should be the specific timer stops but it will not escalate to all other timers?

Comment: That would be fixing the _symptom_ not the _cause_